# can't dup NilClass when using Sanitize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

Alright this probably is the worst error I have found ever.

I have two projects, both using same code:

```
Sanitize.clean(string, Sanitize::Config::BASIC)
```

but one works and another fails.

Problem is similar to this poor guy's post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724342/cant-dup-nilclass-how-to-trace-to-offender

Could anybody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if you pass `nil` into `clean()` instead of a string. Make sure your `string` variable is really a string.